# Item Tree not being populated from link selector in Sitecore 9.2

Tags: hyperlink, sitecore, sitecore9

Whenever we try to add a link using any of the link types (including media links), we get the empty Sitecore Items tree in the dialog window:

[Link Selector Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CevN5.jpg)

The tree list only shows the top level `/sitecore` and nothing else.  Are we missing a configuration somewhere or is this a bug that needs to get reported?

Comment: Any error in browser console when you try to expand the tree?

Comment: No errors in browser or log files.

Answer (score 4):

If there are no errors in the console then you receive a successful response with 200 status, but empty `item[]` in JSON response. So, this is a matter of configuration. Please check the template of your item and make sure that you have specified the correct data source for the link field. In case if the data source path is invalid or empty you will get the empty tree.

Comment: So we need to add a data source for the Sitecore UI to see what is in it's own content tree?  Where would we add that data source?  This is not in relation to a page or website but when you try to add a link to an item in Sitecore UI.  Just for giggles though, I did add a data source pointing to the content level, same results...an empty tree.

Answer (score 0):

This issue stemmed from a pipeline patch that was created to catch Glass Mapper generated processor errors.  Once removed we had the tree list populating as it should.

Comment: I am having this issue but am not aware of a patch for this, can you provide any hints as to what your patch was doing so that I can see if we might have something similar? I just took over a client and so don't have full knowledge of the project yet. I'm not seeing any errors in the log to help me.